# Reconsume message from ActiveMQ

Tags: apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms, spring-camel

When the message is consumed and there is an issue with the processing of the message and it's not saved in the datasource. Since the message is consumed it's not present in ActiveMQ broker and datasource.

Is there a way to reconsume the message from ActiveMQ?

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other users who run into this same issue in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic message loss scenario.

The most robust way to deal with this kind of use-case is by using an XA transaction so that the JMS work and the JDBC work is atomic. This means that if the message consumer has a problem and is not able to insert data in the database then the XA transaction can be rolled back and the message will be put back on the queue so it can be consumed again.

A less robust, but more accessible way to deal with this is to use a transacted JMS session when consuming messages. Once the database work is done then you can acknowledge the message and commit the session. If there is a problem then you rollback the session.